# Sending BufferedImage Over Socket, Extremely Slow

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedimage, server

I'm try to send a BufferedImage to my server and then the server will then send the image to a receiving client. Everything works, just its extremely slow. When I run the server on localhost everything is perfect, the image is almost instantaneously transmitted. But once I upload and run my server on an external platform, it takes almost 30 seconds just to send 1 image. I have even tried tampering with the resolution, but it doesn't seem to effect the transmission time whatsoever. I get 10mbps, and my server is running on 100mbps connection so it definitely shouldn't take 20-30 seconds to send one 765x503 image. I have also tried splitting the image into small pieces and sending each piece in a different thread and different socket, then putting them back together, but that is just as slow as sending the whole image. Which leaves me to believe that I am not doing something efficiently. Thanks so much!!

Sending Client:

```
public void run() {
    try {

        Socket s = new Socket("serverip", port);

        ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(
                s.getOutputStream());

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            objectOutput.writeObject("set name dan");

        while (true) {
            if (client.methods != null
                    && client.methods.getClientImage() != null) {

                // Tools.log("Sending Image Data Array.....");

                // ArrayList<String> data = Conversion
                // .convertToRGBArray(client.methods.getClientImage());
                // Tools.log("Array Size: " + data.size());

                int w = 765;
                int h = 503;
                double d = .5;
                BufferedImage img = resize(client.methods.getClientImage(),
                        (int) (w * d), (int) (h * d));
                objectOutput.writeObject(WriteableBufferimg
                        .WriteBufferimgFactory(resize(img, w, h)));

                // Tools.log("Done sending...");

            }
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return dimg;
}
```

Server:

```
while (true) {

            Object obj = objectInput.readObject();

            if (obj != null) {
                // Tools.log("Object recieved...");
                if (obj instanceof String) {
                    String str = (String) obj;
                    if (str.contains("set name")) {
                        String name = str.replace("set name ", "");
                        Tools.log("Changing " + this.getName() + " to: "
                                + name);
                        this.setName(name);
                    }
                } else {
                    // ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) obj;
                    WriteableBufferimg data = (WriteableBufferimg) obj;
                    if (data != null) {
                        BufferedImage img = data.getImage();

                        String toFind = this.getName();
                        if (this.getName().contains("_app")) {
                            toFind = this.getName().replace("_app", "");
                        } else {
                            toFind = this.getName() + "_app";
                        }
                        for (Node n : Server.nodes) {
                            if (n != null && n.getName().equals(toFind)) {
                                //Tools.log("Sending Data to: " + n.getName());
                                if (n.getObjectOutputStream() != null)
                                    n.getObjectOutputStream().writeObject(
                                            data);
                                else
                                    Tools.log(n.getName()
                                            + "'s out is null");
                                //Tools.log("Complete.");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Receiving Client:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        while (true) {
            Object obj = in.readObject();
            if (obj != null) {
                WriteableBufferimg data = (WriteableBufferimg) obj;
                BufferedImage img = data.getImage();
                if (img != null) {
                    Main.panel.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                } else {
                    Tools.log("img is null");
                }
            }

        }
```

WriteableBufferedimg class:

```
package data;

import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class WriteableBufferimg implements Serializable {

int WIDTH, HIGHT, TransferType, Transparncy, Numcomp;
ColorSpace Colorspace;
int[] Data, BITS;
boolean Alpha, Alphaperm;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static WriteableBufferimg WriteBufferimgFactory(BufferedImage img) {
    Frame frame = new Frame("temp");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(frame);
    mt.addImage(img, 1);
    int W = img.getWidth(frame);
    int H = img.getHeight(frame);
    int[] pixels = new int[W * H];
    PixelGrabber PG = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, W, H, pixels, 0, W);

    try {
        PG.grabPixels();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    ColorModel model = PG.getColorModel();
    int[] bits = model.getComponentSize();
    boolean alpha = model.hasAlpha();
    boolean alphaperm = model.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    int transferType = model.getTransferType();
    int transparncy = model.getTransparency();
    ColorSpace colorspace = model.getColorSpace();
    return new WriteableBufferimg(pixels, W, H, bits, alpha, alphaperm,
            transferType, transparncy, colorspace);

}

public WriteableBufferimg(int[] data, int w, int h, int[] bits,
        boolean alpha, boolean alphaperm, int transferType,
        int transparncy, ColorSpace colorspace) {
    WIDTH = w;
    HIGHT = h;
    Data = data;
    BITS = bits;
    Alpha = alpha;
    Alphaperm = alphaperm;
    TransferType = transferType;
    Transparncy = transparncy;
    Colorspace = colorspace;

}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    DataBufferInt DB = new DataBufferInt(Data, (WIDTH * HIGHT), 0);
    int[] BM = new int[] { 0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff };
    SinglePixelPackedSampleModel SM = new SinglePixelPackedSampleModel(
            DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, WIDTH, HIGHT, BM);

    // creating the raster
    Point P = new Point(0, 0);
    WritableRaster R = Raster.createWritableRaster(SM, DB, P);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HIGHT,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // in this case, P can be replace with null

    // convert the raster to a BufferedImage
    BufferedImage BI = new BufferedImage(bi.getColorModel(), R, false, null);
    return BI;
}

public void Close() {
    try {
        finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `readObject()` doesn't return `null` unless you sent a `null`. If you're not planning on doing that, the test is pointless. Are you sure the time is going on the network operations and not on the resizing operation?

Comment: Ok so I can take that null check out, and the resize does nothing, the amount of time it takes is virtually the same whether I resize or not

Comment: Try `new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()))` and `new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()))`.

Comment: Thats what I have, its just not in the snippets I posted